# Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml in rails - 6 using nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.7

While deploying code using capistrano gem -

- Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.\r
  rake aborted!\r

ruby 2.7
Using rails 6

Comment: What is your database.yml and deploy.rb

Comment: This is a warning and only an issue if you are using multiple databases, if you only have one database you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue. The problem apparently comes from Psych 4.0.0 which makes `Psych.load` refuse to load untrusted data. (See the pull request [Use Psych.safe_load by default #487](https://github.com/ruby/psych/pull/487))

Rails addresses this , but not until [7.0.2.4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1e56b1d1152e8ab74203db30625116844614cc78)

You can restrict `psych` in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'psych', '< 4.0.0'
```

and then a normal `bundle update psych` probably resolves the issue (or you might have to update other gems as I did due to versions which required psych >= 4.0.0)

Comment: This helped me with another issue during rails 6 upgrade: server was not starting and errored with `warning: already initialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::OrmAdapter` and `warning: previous definition of OrmAdapter was here`.
Downgrading rdoc to 6.3 was required, because version 6.4.0 needs psych > 4.0.0. as requirement.